# Has anyone attempted to install vicon_bridge on an ubuntu mate running on a raspberry pi? Seems to have a compatibility issue when making

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error reads /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/atrv/catkin_ws/src/vicon_bridge/vicon_sdk/Vicon_SDK_1.3_Linux/32-bit/libViconDataStreamSDK_CPP.so when searching for -lViconDataStreamSDK_CPP

Seems to be only an issue with raspberry pi, or ARM boards in general? I have successfully used vicon_bridge with my laptop and pc.

Hope someone have some suggestions? Or perhaps I should look for a substitution for the R-pi?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258915/has-anyone-attempted-to-install-vicon_bridge-on-an-ubuntu-mate-running-on-a-raspberry-pi?-seems-to-have-a-compatibility-issue-when-making./) by [yc0123](https://answers.ros.org/users/29676/yc0123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the pre-compiled Vicon library that is part of that package is compiled for Intel processors, and won't work on ARM.

I don't know anything about Vicon, but it would be worth checking their website to see if the provide a version of their SDK that is compiled for ARM.

You may also want to check the github issues for the vicon_bridge package to see if anyone else has reported this before.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yc0123](https://answers.ros.org/users/29676/yc0123/) on 2017-04-11**:
Ahh thanks! Seems like that is indeed the case and seems like I am out of luck for now.
https://github.com/ethz-asl/vicon_bridge/issues/10